# How do grey-background words differ (other than colour)?

Tags: typing-maniac

There is a Flash game called Typing Maniac. It involves typing words that are falling from above.

There are some special words that are given a different background colour, usually meaning that they'll reward a special which is a special power. Words with backgrounds coloured other than (off-)white usually have a special effect and appear more less commonly.

However, some words have a grey background, instead of yellow, red, blue, or purple which reward specials. Words that have a grey background appear as infrequently as words that reward specials. Thirdly, words that have a grey background do not reward a special.

What do grey-background words do?

Comment: According to this link, "grey color words drop immediately if you mis-spell them" and "darker grey words give more points" - http://yh89.wordpress.com/2009/07/11/typing-maniac/

Comment: This game appears to have been taken down and was not archived on Flashpoint Infinity.

Answer (score 0):

[As Batophobia mentioned in their comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/119500/how-do-grey-background-words-differ-other-than-colour#comment161078_119500):

> Note that the grey color words drop immediately if you mis-spell them, so when you have a pile of paper on the flow, almost over-flowing, it might be safer to type other words.
>
> <sub>Source: [*Typing Maniac! - YH89's blog*](https://web.archive.org/web/20090721035919/https://yh89.wordpress.com/2009/07/11/typing-maniac/)</sub>